# How to update a related record only if it exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails 4 application I have these two models:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :sender

  before_save :save_sender

  private

  def save_sender            
    if sender.present?
      sender.update_attributes(user.profile.sender_fields)
    else
      build_sender(user.profile.sender_fields)
    end
  end

end
```

---

```
class Sender < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :invoice

end
```

---

Basically, each `invoice` has a `sender`. Upon creation of an invoice, the sender record should be created automatically. If the invoice is *updated* (instead of *created*), the sender record should be simply updated.

My code above works. But is there a more concise way to do this? Something like *create_or_update*?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the condition.

```
def save_sender
  self.sender ||= build_sender
  sender.update_attributes(user.profile.sender_fields)
end
```

IMO it is more important write readable code than short code. I am not sure which version I would prefer - probably yours...